# Are questions about anime games on topic?

Tags: support

Are questions about anime games on topic?

For example, can I ask questions about the One Piece games?

Comment: Although the question is not exactly the same, you'll find the answers for yours on the question it was marked as a duplicate of.

Comment: In case that link is long or hard to read, the answer to this question is "yes, so long as the question is not about gameplay".